# React Slice container of elements?

Tags: reactjs, slice

In react I have created a variable that contains a list of elements:

```
          let tableRows = TablesByBanner.map((TableByBanner,TableByBannerIndex) =>{
    let allRows = [];
    const firstTableInRow = TableByBanner[0].map((FirstTableRows,FirstTableRowsIndex) =>{
      let menuItems = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < TableByBanner.length; i++) {
          menuItems.push(<td key={FirstTableRowsIndex.toString()+i.toString()+TableByBannerIndex.toString()}></td>);
      }
      if((TableByBannerIndex===0) || (TableByBannerIndex>0 && FirstTableRowsIndex>1 )){
        allRows.push(<tr key={'row'+TableByBannerIndex.toString()+FirstTableRowsIndex.toString()}>{menuItems}</tr>);
      }
    });
    return<>{allRows}</>;
  })
          return (
    <div id="table_holder" className="table-responsive mx-3">
      <table className="table-sm">
        <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

is it possible for me to Slice tableRows so that I only take the first 'nth' elements? so instead of {tableRows} is there a {tableRows.Slice(0,1)} equivalent

Comment: Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice Is there any specific issue you are facing?

Comment: I updated the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is indeed possible to dig into the holding variable, which is an array of objects so:
{tableRows[0].props.children.slice(0,2)}
{tableRows[0].props.children.slice(3)}{tableRows[1]}
allows me to do what I need.
Be interested to see if anyone has a better solution.

Thanks